# iOS7 Implement UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate with Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uikit

Since iOS7 we can create custom transition from view controller to view controller using UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate which allows fine grained transitions.

```
viewController.transitioningDelegate  = transitioningDelegate;
```

I discovered that when using storyboard we already had the opportunity to create custom transitions using a custom `UIStoryboardSegue` but it seems the only way to implement custom transition with a storyboard.

How can I implement a transition delegate while using storyboard ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/.

The idea is to use `- prepareForSegue:` to set the `transitioningDelegate` and the `modalPresentationStyle`to `UIModalPresentationCustom`. Then your transitioning delegate will have to take care of the transition.

Comment: hello, I have a question: I didn't set `modalPresentationStyle` in the `prepareForSegue` and I have a time gap between `animationControllerForPresentedController` and `animateTransition` method  (it was remarkable about 0.4 secs and sometimes even 0.7; my transition animation was 1 second long plus this gap. almost double time.). I tried to find out what is going in this time gap, but this wasn't fault (I think) because I have no process that could create such delay. When I add             modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom this gap is disappeared. Why is so? Thanks.

Comment: Just a guess: if you simplify your setup you may find there is an animation going on. It may be the case that the way you setup your view hierarchy is not allowing you to see this animation.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the following example:
https://github.com/soleares/SOLPresentingFun

It's an implementation of the sample code for WWDC Session 218: Custom Transitions Using View Controllers. It uses storyboards.